# No properties are mapped for type using csv.WriteRecord

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

First,I create a class

```
public class CombatData
{
    public int blackCatHealth;
    public int blackCatAttack;
    public int blackCatWinCount;
    public int whiteCatWinCount;
    public int blackCatDraw;
    public CombatData(int bH,int bA,int bW,int wW,int bD)
    {
        blackCatHealth = bH;
        blackCatAttack = bA;
        blackCatWinCount = bW;
        whiteCatWinCount = wW;
        blackCatDraw = bD;
    }
}
```

Then I try to write

```
var record = new CombatData(blackCat.heath, blackCat.attack, blackCat.winCount, whiteCat.winCount, blackCat.draw);
    using (stream)
    using (writer)
    using (csv)
    {
        csv.WriteRecord(record);
        csv.NextRecord();
    }
```

But It gives me this

```
Unhandled exception. CsvHelper.WriterException: No properties are mapped for type 'CombatData'.
IWriter state:
   Row: 1
   Index: 0
   HeaderRecord:
1
```

The tutorial I read did not mention mapping when it was written
So I don't know what to do, just try the following

```
public sealed class CombatDataMap : ClassMap<CombatData>
{
    public CombatDataMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.blackCatHealth).Index(0);
        Map(m => m.blackCatAttack).Index(1);
        Map(m => m.blackCatWinCount).Index(2);
        Map(m => m.whiteCatWinCount).Index(3);
        Map(m => m.blackCatDraw).Index(4);
    }
}
var record = new CombatData(blackCat.heath, blackCat.attack, blackCat.winCount, whiteCat.winCount, blackCat.draw);
    using (stream)
    using (writer)
    using (csv)
    {
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<CombatDataMap>();
        csv.WriteRecord(record);
        csv.NextRecord();
    }
```

But still there is a problem

```
Unhandled exception. CsvHelper.WriterException: An unexpected error occurred.
IWriter state:
   Row: 2
   Index: 0
   HeaderRecord:
2

 ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'destination')
```

I may be terribly wrong because I don't see anyone else having the same problem as me.
I don't understand why a map is needed.
Please help me.

Also my English is not good, this is the result of google translate, if there is a problem, I'm sorry

Comment: What happens if you use properties instead of fields?  I.e. `public int blackCatHealth { get; set; }`?

Comment: Replacing fields with properties fixes the *`No properties are mapped for type 'CombatData'.`* error, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/odhHNm.  But I cannot reproduce the  *`System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'destination')`* error; given a classmap, everything works OK.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/KGM6QN.  Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] for your second problem -- or ask a second question, as the preferred format for questions on stack overflow is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735).

Comment: Your code fragment (which does not compile) appears to be writing a single record.  Are you actually writing multiple records in a loop?  Might you be disposing the `stream`, `writer` and `csv` inside the loop rather than outside?

Comment: @dbc Thank you very much, the problem of needing to be mapped after changing the attribute to a field is solved

Comment: @dbc Another problem was solved when I wrote the using outside the loop, you are awesome

Comment: @dbc In the future I will take care to share a minimal reproducible example, thank you again

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the configuration to use `Fields` instead of `Properties`.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        MemberTypes = CsvHelper.Configuration.MemberTypes.Fields
    };
    
    var record = new CombatData(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); 
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, config))
    {
        csv.WriteRecord(record);
        csv.NextRecord();
    }
}

public class CombatData
{
    public int blackCatHealth;
    public int blackCatAttack;
    public int blackCatWinCount;
    public int whiteCatWinCount;
    public int blackCatDraw;
    public CombatData(int bH, int bA, int bW, int wW, int bD)
    {
        blackCatHealth = bH;
        blackCatAttack = bA;
        blackCatWinCount = bW;
        whiteCatWinCount = wW;
        blackCatDraw = bD;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, doing this for fields also works, Thank you